# How do I list databases with the python asyncio mongo client, motor?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-asyncio

I'm having problems get [motor](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to list databases with asyncio.

The following code:

```py
import asyncio
import motor.motor_asyncio
import sys

async def list():
    print(sys.version)
    print(motor.version)
    client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://admin:password@mongo/")
    for db in client.list_databases():
        print(db)
        print(type(db))
        await db


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(list())
```

fails with the following error

```py
2.1.0
3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:48:26) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)]
<Future pending cb=[run_on_executor.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/motor/frameworks/asyncio/__init__.py:80]>
<class '_asyncio.Future'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(list())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "test.py", line 13, in list
    await db
RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
```

I found this issue which seems related https://bugs.python.org/issue37172. This also seems to fail with python 3.7.7 and motor 2.0.0.

As a horrible work around at the moment, I'm using `pymongo` exclusively for this operation - but I would prefer not to do this.

Comment: I think you need to await `list_databases`. Either that or try `async for` with it.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both of those things. Niether f them worked.

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking how to use `pymongo` instead of this?

Comment: Nope, I want to get the asyncio code working. At the moment, I have a horrible hack using pymongo because i wanted to make progress - but I'd prefer to remove this horrible hack. (this is in a test hareness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list the names of all databases, you can use [list_database_names](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/asyncio_motor_client.html#motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient.list_database_names):

```
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient()
dbs = await client.list_database_names()
print(dbs)  # ["admin", "config", "local", "..."]
```

Get a cursor over the databases, you need use [list_databases](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/asyncio_motor_client.html#motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient.list_databases).

```
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient()
cursor = await client.list_databases()
try:
    while True:
        db = await cursor.next()
        print(db)  # {'name': 'admin', 'sizeOnDisk': 40960, 'empty': False}, ...
except StopAsyncIteration:
    pass
```

With `list_databases` you can also use [listDatabases commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/).